# Android bluetooth txpower

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Android Bluetooth and I cannot read the `txPower` to calculate distance. I read that this value is available from Oreo, but on android 10 or 9 it is alway 127 when use `result.txPower`

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            
            manageResult(result!!)

        }
```

Someone has suggestions?

Comment: any update on that @Skip?